# Is there a Office Communicator Automation API for Windows Mobile 6.0

Tags: windows, windows-mobile, office-communicator

Is there an Windows Mobile Office Communicator client API to develop a plugin using OCS.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no there is not.  But what could be done is to deploy Communicator Web Access (CWA) and build a Windows Moble App that interacts with the CWA backend.